# Go to definition not working in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Editing a PHP file with VS Code. `Go to definition` not working for the JavaScript code in the file. 
How to get `Go to definition` to work?

(VS Code does complain when I open the PHP file. "Cannot validate since no PHP executable is set".)

Comment: "GOTO definition not working for the Javascript code". A goto for JS? Does JS even have a goto?

Comment: JS only has gotos via a preprocessor.

Comment: Hey Stephen, the 60s called and asked if they could have their `goto` statements back.

Comment: Do you mean the functionality `Go to definition` which takes you to the implementation or do you mean `goto` as in the language construct?

Comment: F12 go to definition.  How else should I phrase the question?

Comment: a `GOTO` is something completely different :D https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the JavaScript is defined `inline` in the `.php` file then Visual Studio Code will not be able to Go to the defintion of the JavaScript function.

It can only `Go to definition` when the editor can resolve/figure out a path for a function/class/variable/module.

Comment: I see.  So best practice is to separate the web page into two files. The .php file. And a 2nd .js file that contains all the javascript embedded in that page.